Comparing stimulation efficacy under 3 conditions
I have a dataset where I am comparing 3 drug conditions (drug a, drug b, drug a+b) and my read out is the number of cells in a petri dish that respond to the drugs.




DrugB-00mg
DrugB-10mg
DrugB-20mg
DrugB-30mg




Drug A-00mg






Drug A-10mg






Drug A-20mg






Drug A-30mg







As such, within each petri dish, I test drug A in isolation (first column) as well as B in isolation (first row) as well as cocktail combinations in other cells giving a total of 16 conditions (including the first condition where no drugs are added)
My readout is number of cells that respond to the drug treatment (it's a number that varies between 0-50) and I have done this in 5x biological replicates.
I want to determine if the drug a+b conditions at various levels are statistically different to drug a only or drug b only.
Would the best form of testing be some sort of repeated measure kruskal wallis?
Many thanks in advance
EDIT: Updated the question and provided a table to hopefully provide more clarity

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Can you clarifiy the setup; I count 4 factors for A alone, 4 for B alone, and 16 for A+B, so a total of 24 "factors"? Is this correct? And then I read that for each of the 24 combinations you have 5 petri dishes? Correct? So a grand total of 120 petri dishes? And your outcome variable is a count (discrete, integer); a number of cells? Please answer by editing your post (many contributors do not read all the comments)

Hi @jginestet thanks for the comment and I have updated my question accordingly to hopefully provide clarity. Thanks again for your assistance and taking the time to assess my question

Thanks for the updates. That is more clear. However... Rows 2-3 seem to be all the same? And columns 3 and 4 are the same? Last, is there really a set of petri dishes with no drug (no A, no B, aka a control)?

Damn my terrible copy and paste. i've adjusted the column and row headers. it scales up from 10->30 for each drug. In the condition where there's 0mg for each drug I'm adding the vehicle (drug diluent i.e. saline) just to make sure the cells aren't reacting to just topical application of just anything.
So in essence a petri dish would have some drugs in solution applied to them in a pseudorandomized fashion until all 16 conditions have been applied to the cells. I have 5x biological replicates to trial the 16 combinations.
